# Converting (time domain) Fluctuations to Power Spectral Density (PSD)

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

I have a Voltage signal, $V$, with fluctuations that go as:
$$
   \langle\delta V(\tau)^2\rangle=\ln f_a\tau
$$

Here $f_a$ is an attempt frequency from an [Ahrennius Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation).  According to many papers, "it is well-known that this leads to a 1/f" spectrum.  I just don't see how.

I believe that the PSD (Power Spectral Density), $S_V$, should be equal to:
$$
S_V=\frac{1}{T}|\delta V(f)|^2=\int\langle\delta V(\tau)\delta V(0)\rangle e^{2\pi i f\tau}d\tau
$$

But I don't see how any of that is calculable (or $=1/f$) from where I am starting from.  Thanks!